# How does a C-style struct with a bitfield get represented in a Rust #[repr(C)] struct?

Tags: c, struct, rust, bit-fields

I have a C struct defined as:

```c
struct my_c_s {
    u_char          *ptr;
    unsigned        flag_a:1;
    unsigned        flag_b:1;
    int             some_num;
}
```

How would `flag_a` and `flag_b` be represented?

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct my_rust_s {
    pub ptr: *const u_char,
    //pub flag_a: ?,
    //pub flag_b: ?,
    pub some_num: ::libc::c_int,
}
```

<strike>Can I declare them as `bool`s?</strike>  Or does that whole thing need to be some sort of set of bits with a single field, and then I bitmask them out?

e.g.  `pub flag_bits: ::libc::c_uint,`

Comment: i think bool is 1 byte not 1 bit.

Comment: Did you look at [this crate](https://crates.io/crates/bitfield)?

Comment: *How would `flag_a` and `flag_b` be represented?*  There's no standard way that bit fields are represented in just C alone, let alone a standard cross-language representation.  If you care about portability at all - even between different compilers on the exact same system - you don't use bit fields.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I don't really know much about bitfields, I'm trying to interop with existing code that uses them (nginx internals).  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't.

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/314) about supporting bitfields, which doesn't seem to be active. In the issue, [@retep998 explains how bitfields are handled in `winapi`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/314#issuecomment-253099578). That might be helpful if you need to handle bitfields in C interface.

OP seems to aim at C interoperation, but if you just need bitfields functionality, there are several solutions.

- You should always consider simple redundant solution: avoid bitfields and let fields align naturally.
- [`bitfield`](https://crates.io/crates/bitfield), according to [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229167/how-does-a-c-style-unsigned-field1-struct-field-get-represented-in-a-rust#comment77424674_45229167) -- I didn't know that, but it seems to provide C bitfields equivalent.
- [`bitflags`](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags). This seems suitable for bit-based flags, which typically represented as `enum` in C.
- `#[repr(packed)]` if you just want to pack fields to some degree, ignoring alignment. The fields will still be aligned to byte boundary.
- [`bit-vec`](https://crates.io/crates/bit-vec) if you need homogenious arrays of bits.